# No SQL Server Data Tools in VS 2013 ultimate installed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have no SQL Server Data Tool in Visual Studio 2013.

SSDT should be included in VS2013? [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/31/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29)

How can I install them?

I tried to install [BI for VS 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) but still don't have any SQL functions in VS.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a data connection in the Server Explorer tab?

Comment: yes, this works. But there has to be a SQL Server Explorer tab in addition?!

Comment: No, no extra tab. The enhanced integration started in VS2012. You can still use SSMS for writing SQL etc, or just do it directly in VS.

Comment: SQL tools like schema comparison are not installed

Comment: Which vs you are using? premium, professional, ultimate, or express?

Comment: ultimate, as mentioned in the title

Comment: I have added answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools` is checked when you install VS.
[image]

Comment: Install VS2013 first, then install Update 2.

Comment: yesterday it was not listed. Now it is. I deinstalled some sql and VS stuff in between. This is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tools like schema comparison are in SQL menu. SQL menu is not visible till any database project OR .scmp file OR file where its context is available is open.

[image]

For more details, refer:

http://pranavwithyou.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/schema-data-comparison-of-two-databases-with-visual-studio/

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS108

---

**Update**

Got this link on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

[image]

Download latest VS2013 Update 2 through extension update or by link http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs

For SSDT-BI for VS 2013 install:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

after installation restart Visual studio.

Lets hope, it should work then.

Comment: As mentioned I have no SQL menu in VS. When opening a .scmp file only the xml text is openend.

Comment: Open a database project & then try. SQL menu must be visible then. Refer msdn video, in initial video there is no SQL menu visible till database project is open.

Comment: There is no database project template. SSDT seems not to be installed correctly.

Comment: Do Sql server is installed on your machine

Comment: Got it, make sure vs 2013 is updated, I am adding link in answer

Comment: It is latest Version.

Comment: Install SSDT-BI for VS 2013 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313  , updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't have SQL menu, however I found it in Tools -> SQL Server

[image]

Comment: Same here - I wonder if this is by design. Annoying ,guessing this is a "product improvement" Seems that MS absolutely LOVE to FIX what IS NOT BROKE ;)